Python Aiogram3 payment stripe
I got "Error: Bot Timeout"
I don't have any errors in my terminal when I start polling my app. But when the Checkout process occurs in telegram an error window pops up "Error: Bot Timeout" How can fix this error? Ty!

    @payment_router.callback_query(F.data == 'Invoice Order')
    async def send_invoice(call: CallbackQuery):
        logging.debug('Entered send_invoice')
        await call.answer()
        try:
           await call.message.answer_invoice(
                title='Product',
                description='Product description',
                payload='payload',
                provider_token=stripe.api_key,
                currency='USD',
                prices=prices,
                max_tip_amount=2000,
                suggested_tip_amounts=[250, 500, 750, 1000],
                start_parameter="1",
                provider_data=None,
                need_name=True,
                need_phone_number=True,
                need_email=False,
                need_shipping_address=True,
                send_phone_number_to_provider=False,
                send_email_to_provider=False,
                is_flexible=True,
                disable_notification=False,
                protect_content=False,
                reply_to_message_id=None,
                allow_sending_without_reply=True,
                reply_markup=None,
                request_timeout=90
            )
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception("Error in send_invoice")
            print("Error in send_invoice", e)


@payment_router.pre_checkout_query()
async def process_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query: PreCheckoutQuery):
    logging.exception("Error in send_invoice")
    try:
        await pre_checkout_query.answer(ok=True)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Error in process_pre_checkout_query")
        print("Error in process_pre_checkout_query", e)


